# Load contents to an ajax tab when the user clicks on it

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, tabs, asp.net-ajax

I have a page(C#-asp.net application) with more than 5 ajax tabs that gets data on page load. Since it takes a long time, i want to populate the tab contents only when the user clicks on the tab.not able to find any event in tab panel. BTW i'm using an AJAX Tab container Please Advice me ASAP.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Are you loading different pages in different tabs.

Comment: Well I do not know the tab container, but I guess you have to change the databinding and remove it from the OnPageLoad and shift it to the OnClick event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set  AutoPostBack="true" add ActiveTabChanged to tab control. For details go **[here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Tabs/Tabs.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

Consider to extract tabs content to user controls and load them into active tab in Page_Load method depending on ActiveTabIndex property